# add a blur overlay and unblur some views to highlight them for the user

Tags: ios, swift, blur

I want to add some instructions on my app when a user first opens a ViewController, so I will add a blur super view and I will unblur some components and show their functionalities as the [this demo image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cr1FTfK8jcZKfJL5pnB-5LIp6hOo-W82) shows. So my question is, how can I unblur specific components of the super view to highlight them?

Comment: I would do it by changing the zPositions of the view layers. So at first you have that semi-transparent view on top of everything, then you change the zPosition of a button so that it comes in front of the semi-transparent view. And so on. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition)

Comment: Hello Razvan, thank you for your reply, add it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would achieve that effect by changing the zPositions of the view layers. At first you have that semi-transparent view on top of everything and then you change the zPosition of a button so that it comes in front of the semi-transparent view.

If you need to unblur another component later in your flow, you can change the button zPosition back and bring forward the new component.

You can read more about the zPosition here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410884-zposition